# Enable ~/Sites Folder

Tags: permission, apache

I have been following [this](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-osx-109-mavericks) tutorial in order to setup my local `~/Sites` folder.

`/etc/apache2/users/carloabelli.conf`:

```
<Directory "/Users/carloabelli/Sites/">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have restarted apache numerous times. Whenever I go the the url `http://localhost/~carloabelli` I get the following response:

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~carloabelli on this server.
```

What else do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Permissions set on the `/Users/<username>/Sites` Folder.

The "web user" (i think on Mac www is used for this) must have the Rights to read and execute so in most cases a `chmod o+rx /Users/<username>/Sites` should be enough.

If this doesn't work let us know what you are using to control your Webserver? OSX Server or MAMP or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In your httpd.conf file you will see User and Group at the top
You have to sent

```
User <your uer name>
Group www (no change needed)
```

You have to change it because the default `apache` user `_www` which will not have access to the directories under `<user>`, `_www` will have access only to `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` So you have to change the user in httpd.conf.  So that apache can access the files under your user Documents.  Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @DavidRicherby, Yes you are right.. let me update my answer and follow this hearafter.

Comment: Thank you, I replaced the User with my username and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Aside from getting the permissions correct for reading and executing the Sites directory and its parents, recent configs, i.e, 10.12, require additional configuration options in several files:

`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.` -- uncomment:

```
    LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
    ...
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

`/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf` -- Uncomment:

```
    Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

Create a file `/etc/apache2/users/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE.conf` with:

```
<Directory "/Users/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If the lines are commented out, your per-user file will not be read.

Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/225346/how-do-i-setup-a-localhost-using-the-sites-folder-on-my-mac/566617#comment1813417_566617 and preceeding.